# Huawei E367 USB mode switch

Tags: modem, huawei, mode

Hi! I tried mode switching, but it always fails to switch.
The USB storage is detached, but the mode switching fails and the product id stays at "1446" and doesn't change to "1506".
Here is the script that I am using:

```
DefaultVendor= 0x12d1  
DefaultProduct=0x1446

TargetVendor=  0x12d1
TargetProductList="1001,1406,140b,140c,1412,141b,14ac,1506"

CheckSuccess=20

MessageEndpoint= 0x01
MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"
```

Source: http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Huawei_E367 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution add -I to the command.
I hope this helps.
So the command would be something like this.

```
sudo usb_modeswitch -v 0x12d1 -p 0x1446 -V 0x12d1 -P 0x1506 -m 0x01 -M 55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000  -I
```

Or you can use a config file and add -I.

Comment: Awesome! Ive tried everything to get my Huawei E367 to work on my Raspberry Pi, and nothing worked. Youre -I saved my day/week :-) You should really mark your own answer as accepted. Thx